# Awk insert a command output into a variable

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

I am trying to insert the output below into the variable `x`. The output is a string. I have done this before.

```
k="psz"
```

And when I do this it works and i get the expected output when doing echo $x

```
x=$( awk -v a="k" -F '[:,]' '{ if($1 == "psz")  print $5 }' /etc/passwd )
```

But when i try to use this one below it doesn't work

```
x=$( awk -v a="k" -F '[:,]' '{ if($1 == a)  print $5 }' /etc/passwd )
```

It does not work, echo `$x` gives me a blank line.

Comment: In the second one `k` isn't defined before `if($1 == k)`, you mean `if($1 == "k")`? or `if($1 == a)`?

Comment: The test should be ```if ($1 == a)``` not ```k```, and if you want ```a``` to be set with the value of ```k```, then you should pass ```-v a=$k``` instead.

Comment: yea yea you are right!
It's a not k. it's a
i made a typo.

Comment: the problem still exists !

Comment: Check my answer. I guess you're still passing ```-va=k``` instead of ```-va=$k```, the right form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `a` with the string `k` and not the value of variable `$k`. If you set it right, the code will work fine. Look:

```
k='accdias'
x=$(awk -va=$k 'BEGIN{FS=":"} $1==a {print $5}' /etc/passwd)
echo $x
Antonio Dias
```

I'm editing this to show another way of passing variable values to your `awk` program without using `-v`:

```
k='accdias'
x=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} $1==ARGV[2] {print $5}' /etc/passwd $k)
echo $x
Antonio Dias
```

On the above code `ARGV[0]` will be set to `awk`, `ARGV[1]` will be set to `/etc/passwd`, and finally `ARGV[2]` will be set to `$k` value, which is `accdias` on that example.

---

Edits from Ed Morton (see comments below):

```
k='accdias'
x=$(awk -v a="$k" 'BEGIN{FS=":"} $1==a {print $5}' /etc/passwd)
echo "$x"
Antonio Dias

k='accdias'
x=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; a=ARGV[2]; ARGV[2]=""; ARGC--} $1==a {print $5}' /etc/passwd "$k")
echo "$x"
Antonio Dias
```

Comment: yea you are right i found it.
Do you know how i can put an if else into the awk?

Comment: you have the right idea for `if/else` in your OP. Just `{ if($1 == a)  {print $5} else {print "no match"} }` . Good luck.

Comment: No worries. About the if/else, something like this will do it ```if (condition){commands} else {commands}```.

Comment: on the second answer you gave...
if you pass the ARGV[2] into $1, how will you be able to use the first field of each record ? the $1 variable

Comment: You must quote your shell variables (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and if you don't set ARGV[2] to null after reading it then awks going to try to open `accdias` like an input file, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1745001. Also if you don't put a space after the `-v` (i.e. `-v a="$k"`) then it makes the script unnecessarily gawk-only.

Comment: @EdMorton, you're absolutely right on all those (as always!). Thanks for the heads up and, if you don't mind, could you please fix the answer? I don't know how to do it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, Ed! That will sure help the OP.